# Why or when should I use messages queues such as RabbitMQ, ZeroMQ in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, message-queue, zeromq

Hello awesome Erlang community!

I'm making a little project that contains a Client and a Backend. (Complicated.. right?) :)

I'm making it in erlang.

The client and backend will be two separate processes and I'm wondering if I would need to (or should I) use some sort of message queue to get them to interact?

I know I can get them to interact using their PIDs and send messages using the "!" operator.

I guess what I'm trying to say is I'm struggling with finding an answer for this question:

***"Why or when should I use message queues such as RabbitMQ, ZeroMQ in Erlang"?***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use a messaging library when you need something that the native message passing facility won't provide.

These include:

- If you need to guarantee that your messages are processed at
  least once, exactly once etc. (i.e. transaction)
- If your system load is such that it would be convenient if you could
  hold your messages on disk instead of memory (persistence)
- You need other bells and whistles like security, interop with other
  systems, complex messaging pattern (routing) etc.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for a messaging component when you need to decouple the different layers of my system. Also, a messaging component allows you to be able to do different integration patters with your messages/requests like topic/fanout/route based on headers...
A messaging system is also used for scalibility purposes, so you can have multiple instances of the same process running simultaneously consuming from the same queue.

Last thing I want to mention is that RabbitMQ is a message broker but ZeroMQ is not, it is a messaging library.

Answer (score 1):

If you can sacrifice reliability for performance, use ZeroMq.

If you need reliability (message persistence, etc), and can give up some performance, use a brokered solution like RabbitMq.